# Problems with creating Python script that creates report with all changes in Excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, excel-2010, data-analysis

I'm having a bit of a major problem with writing a Python script that creates a report of all changes in an Excel file.

Script should:

a) Examine a file on a "custom path"

- if there were changes the script should create new .xlsx file same to the file that was changed and save it for next script run, and send report with all changes that were made.
- if there were no changes script does nothing, or gives output similar to "Everything is ok".

b) Script should only check 1 Worksheet in an Excel file, and detect changes in 3 or 4 columns.

I found a Python Excel library but I'm still not managing to create any code that works.

If someone can help with this, or if someone has any code that I can use it would be much appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now()
now = datetime.now()
now.strftime("%H:%M")
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
with open('file path', 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read()
    hasher.update(buf)

with open('log.txt', 'a+') as f:
    print("File was checked at", now.strftime("%H:%M"), "this is hash:",            
hasher.hexdigest(),"\n", file=f)
```

This is the code i have at the moment.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've only managed to get SHA256 hash of file that lets me know if there were any changes, save the hash and use it for check next time, but then i need to look the file myself. I need to get smth like a report so i can just edit the changes.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried and exactly where is the problem.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please refer to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and read it carefully in order to learn how to post a question correctly in the community. Please edit your post to add the code you put on the last comment, so we can try your minimum reproducible example and help you troubleshoot the issue.